# Can't connect to MySQL Database with Java JDBC

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, workbench

I created a simple class to test the communication to my localhost database, that I created with Mysql Workbench. The Mysql Server is running. The JDBC Driver is added to the Classpath of my project.

```
public class Database
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
            throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException
    {
        Connection connection = null;
        String serverName = "localhost:3306";
        String databaseName = "detector_tests";
        String url = "jdbc:mysql://" + serverName + "/" + databaseName
                + "?useSSL=TRUE";

        String username = "simon";
        String password = "password123";
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
    }
}
```

When I run the program I get the followning Exception:

> Exception in thread "main"
>   com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications
>   link failure
>
> The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds
>   ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.     at
>   com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:172)
>     at
>   com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:64)
>     at
>   com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:862)
>     at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.(ConnectionImpl.java:444)
>     at
>   com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:230)
>     at
>   com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:226)
>     at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)  at
>   Database.main(Database.java:17) Caused by:
>   com.mysql.cj.exceptions.CJCommunicationsException: Communications link
>   failure
>
> The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds
>   ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>     at
>   com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:59)
>     at
>   com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:103)
>     at
>   com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:149)
>     at
>   com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createCommunicationsException(ExceptionFactory.java:165)
>     at
>   com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.negotiateSSLConnection(NativeProtocol.java:355)
>     at
>   com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeAuthenticationProvider.negotiateSSLConnection(NativeAuthenticationProvider.java:789)
>     at
>   com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeAuthenticationProvider.proceedHandshakeWithPluggableAuthentication(NativeAuthenticationProvider.java:499)
>     at
>   com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeAuthenticationProvider.connect(NativeAuthenticationProvider.java:217)
>     at
>   com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.connect(NativeProtocol.java:1411)
>     at com.mysql.cj.NativeSession.connect(NativeSession.java:165)   at
>   com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:982)
>     at
>   com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:852)
>     ... 6 more Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException:
>   java.security.cert.CertificateException:
>   java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Path does not chain
>   with any of the trust anchors     at
>   sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(Unknown Source)  at
>   sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(Unknown Source)
>     at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(Unknown Source)
>     at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Unknown Source)  at
>   sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Unknown Source)    at
>   sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)     at
>   sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source)
>     at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)    at
>   sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)     at
>   com.mysql.cj.protocol.ExportControlled.performTlsHandshake(ExportControlled.java:213)
>     at
>   com.mysql.cj.protocol.StandardSocketFactory.performTlsHandshake(StandardSocketFactory.java:206)
>     at
>   com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeSocketConnection.performTlsHandshake(NativeSocketConnection.java:99)
>     at
>   com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.negotiateSSLConnection(NativeProtocol.java:350)
>     ... 13 more Caused by: java.security.cert.CertificateException:
>   java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Path does not chain
>   with any of the trust anchors     at
>   com.mysql.cj.protocol.ExportControlled$X509TrustManagerWrapper.checkServerTrusted(ExportControlled.java:280)
>     at
>   sun.security.ssl.AbstractTrustManagerWrapper.checkServerTrusted(Unknown
>   Source)   ... 25 more Caused by:
>   java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Path does not chain
>   with any of the trust anchors     at
>   sun.security.provider.certpath.PKIXCertPathValidator.validate(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   sun.security.provider.certpath.PKIXCertPathValidator.engineValidate(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.security.cert.CertPathValidator.validate(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   com.mysql.cj.protocol.ExportControlled$X509TrustManagerWrapper.checkServerTrusted(ExportControlled.java:273)
>     ... 26 more

It appears that I need to add some kind of certificate or something. I m not sure, because I m quite new to databases. Anyone with the same experience or a solution? If you need anymore information I'm happy to edit the post.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: _"java.security.cert.CertificateException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Path does not chain with any of the trust anchors "_

Comment: What does it mean? Do I need to configure Eclipse, the Database or something on my Windows OS?

Comment: Have you tried Googling that error message? I see a lot of posts and responses...

Comment: Yes, couldnt find anything useful.

Answer (score 3):

Seems you are trying to connect mysql database along with a certificate. If you are connecting to MySQL instance through TLS, you need to have a trust store to keep your certificates. Refer to [this document](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/5.1/en/connector-j-reference-using-ssl.html) to create MySQL connection along with a TLS connection.

But, you can ignore TLS validation by setting FALSE for "useSSL" in MySQL connection URL. Your code will be as follows.

```html
public class Database
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
            throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException
    {
        Connection connection = null;
        String serverName = "localhost:3306";
        String databaseName = "detector_tests";
        String url = "jdbc:mysql://" + serverName + "/" + databaseName
                + "?useSSL=FALSE";

        String username = "simon";
        String password = "password123";
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
    }
}
```

Hope this will be the answer to your question.